# How to add spacing between the title, author and logo on book cover spine?

Tags: bookcover

I'm using the bookcover package for this.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  spinewidth=1cm,
  markcolor=black,]{bookcover}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../images}}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{gold}{rgb}{0.68, 0.57, 0.35}
\definecolor{NavyBlue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.14, 0.4}

\begin{document}
  \begin{bookcover}
    \bookcovercomponent{center}{spine}{
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{     
        \LARGE\bfseries\color{gold}
        My Long Book Spine Title
      }
      \vfill
      \includegraphics[scale=0.0125]{logo}
    }
  \end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming you want them in vertical column, separate them with \par and \vspace. or \vfill.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thanks.  The \vfill did the trick.  I updated the MWE.